# implement sub-resource in REST API

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

I need to implement sub resource in REST API

URL will be like :
https://localhost:8080/v1/student/{id}?include=address,qualification,login

so address,qualification and login are three sub resource , which will be included if we add this is query param .Subresource can be database call or rest call to other service

the issue is happening in implementation side , I have taken @RequestParam List include

so currently i am writing like this in service class

```
 public Student getStudentDetail(Integer id ,List<String> include){
    Student student = new Student();
    // setting student details
    for(String itr: include){
    if(itr=="address"){
    student.setAddress(repo.getAddress(id));
    }
    if(itr=="qualification"){
    student.setQualication(repo.getQualification(id));
    }
    if(itr=="login"){
    student.setLogin(client.getLogin(id));// here client in Rest Call for 
    }


   }
    return student;
    }
```

Student Class:

```
@Data
public Class Student{
private String id;

private List<Address> address;

private List<Qualification> qualification;

private Login login; 
}
```

so here i need to add if condition for every subresource , can you suggest any better approach to do it or any design principal.

There is another approach to get the repository method name at runtime using reflection API , but it is adding extra overhead to call .

Another Approach can be:

I can use strategy Design pattern

```
Abstract Class 

public Abstract class Subresource{
public Student getSubresouce(Integer id,Student student){}
}

public class Address extends Subresource{
@Autowired
Databaserepo repo;

public Student getSubresource(Integer id , Student student){
  return student.setAddress(repo.getAddress(id));
}
}

public class Login extends Subresource{
@Autowired
RestClient client;

public Student getSubresource(Integer id, Student student){
 return student.setLogin(client.getLogin(id));
}
}
```

but in this approach i am unable to write logic in service

```
  public Student getStudentDetail(Integer id ,List<String> include){
        Student student = new Student();
        // setting student details
        for(String itr: include){
       // Need to fill logic
// Help me here to define logic to use strategy oattern
       }
        return student;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is Projections. From this [link](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li/wiki/How-to-use-projections-in-Java)

> Projections are a way for a client to request only specific fields
>   from an object instead of the entire object. Using projections when
>   you only need a few fields from an object is a good way to
>   self-document your code, reduce payload of responses, and even allow
>   the server to relax an otherwise time consuming computation or IO
>   operation.

If you are using Spring [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-projections-excerpts) are some examples.

Comment: Thanks for reply , projection help in database call only , if i want to see login detail of student , I have to call a rest client to get the details and the put into student record


for(String itr: include){
if(itr=="login"){
student.setQualication(client.getLogin(id));
}

Can you help me with any design pattern which i can use or any example

Comment: Maybe the solution here is to go with a generic Response class. Then you can serialize the Student object as a Map, and apply a filter to include only those keys that are in the include param?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i can not change the format of json , also again there i have to write if else , i can not write if  else it will add cyclomatric complexity, Can you help me in filling service logic the Strategy pattern .